# Django strange NoReverseMatch

Tags: django

I haven't found a solution to this online yet. By all accounts this should be working, but I'm still getting this error.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^orders/', include('project.orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
    ...]
```

**orders/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(
        regex=r'^create/$',
        view=views.CreateOrderView.as_view(),
        name='create'
    ),
    ...]
```

**orders/views.py**

```
class UploadSampleSheetView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):

    def post(self, request):
        ...
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
            return reverse("orders:create", kwargs={'sample_sheet':sample})

class CreateOrderView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'pages/complete_order.html')
```

The error message is

> Reverse for 'create' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'sample_sheet': Sample: Sample object}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['orders/create/$']

But when I just go to that url (/orders/create/) the page is there...

I've tried

```
return reverse("orders:create", kwargs={'sample_sheet':sample})

return reverse("create", kwargs={'sample_sheet':sample})

return reverse(orders:create, kwargs={'sample_sheet':sample})

return reverse(CreateOrderView, kwargs={'sample_sheet':sample})
```

But none work. Other answers here haven't helped me so far, nor have the docs. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `kwargs` from below code as mentioned in your question and `HttpResponseRedirect` for redirect to another url

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("orders:create"))
```

Comment: This solution works, but I'd like to render my template with the data in `kwargs={'sample_sheet':sample}`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return reverse("create")
```

But I'd strongly advise to think about the way you name your route.
Maybe call this '`order_create`' so that if you have update or delete view, you'll create respectively '`order_update`' and '`order_delete`' route, and this will make your application easier to maintain.

And you should avoid using `def post()` because Django handles forms in a very nice way. When you use the `FormView` class many things are prepared for you, and you could use `UpdateView` and `CreateView` and so on. Example:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class SocieteUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    model = Societe
    form_class = SocieteForm
    template_name = 'crud/societe/update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('societe_list')
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I've had trouble finding good documentation/examples of the generic View classes. The django docs for each of them just seem to list the mixins in each class. Is there somewhere I could learn more about each of these classes?