# How to route a multi-part form in django

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django.

I'd like my users to be able to place orders. For this kind of order, the user uploads a csv. The app parses, the CSV, serializes the data, and then needs to show the user a new view with the data and a "confirm order" button. I'm not sure how to do this in django.

```
class UploadSampleSheetView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):

    form_class = UploadSampleSheetForm
    template_name = 'pages/upload.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):

        uploaded_sample_sheet = self.request.FILES['uploaded_sample_sheet']
        sample = _parse_sample_sheet_to_sample_model(uploaded_sample_sheet)
        sample.save()

        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("orders:create") # how do I return another view populated with data here? 


class CreateOrderView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    model = Order
    form_class = NewOrderForm
    template_name = 'pages/complete_order.html'
```

What I'm looking for is some way that, on success, the `UploadSampleSheetView` can return a CreateOrderView with `sample` data.

In general, *I'd love to be pointed to a reference about how to build user flows like this one*. How does one view defer to another? I'm seeing a lot of `return HttpResponseRedirect('url')` which seems a little messy. How do I pass data around views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormViews are supposed to return HttpResponseRedirects. They take in the data, process it, and re-route you to a place that makes sense. I think your question is, how can I get routed to the appropriate place.

The documentation isn't very clear on this, so it's a very valid question. But, you can override get_success_url to take in an argument. So, you would add this:

```
def get_success_url(self, sample_id):
    return reverse('create_order', kwargs={"pk" : sample_id})
```

and also change form_valid to

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    uploaded_sample_sheet = self.request.FILES['uploaded_sample_sheet']
    sample = _parse_sample_sheet_to_sample_model(uploaded_sample_sheet)
    sample.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url(sample.id))
```

Don't worry, you're not missing out on anything by skipping super().form_valid() -- [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms) (scroll just a little down) say that all `form_valid` does by default is redirect to `success_url`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I have issues with this solution, which is part of what caused my issues in the first place. Specifically I get a "NoReverseMatch" (you can find it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46518194/django-strange-noreversematch). This problem stems from adding the `kwargs` to reverse. I think I might just not be matching the pattern in the URLs? I'm not sure.

Comment: What version of django are you using? Also, can you write out the line of code that has `reverse` in it? And, the URL that you are trying to match? With those we can get to the answer

Comment: Thanks Sam! I just didn't have a URL for it. Can you point me to a reference about why `pk` is magic? My googling so far hasn't gotten me too far.

Comment: In django, you can have two types of URL variables, named and unnamed. A pattern with a named variable looks like "^path/(?P<named_variable>\d+)/". If that called a function with signature `def path_function(self, *args, **kwargs)`, you would get the id from `kwargs.named_variable`. A pattern like "^path/(\d+)/" is an unnamed variable, which you get in your function through `args[0]`.

Comment: Also, I don't mean this patronizingly, but if you're new to Django you should definitely work through the entire official tutorial. Django's a really heavy framework, and there's always an easy, right, and unintuitive way of doing things. You learn how to do most things you'd want there, and it only takes a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Form Wizard](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html)

> Django comes with an optional “form wizard” application that splits forms across multiple Web pages. It maintains state in one of the backends so that the full server-side processing can be delayed until the submission of the final form.
>
> You might want to use this if you have a lengthy form that would be too unwieldy for display on a single page. The first page might ask the user for core information, the second page might ask for less important information, etc.

Harder to use, but very useful and flexible.

```
# views.py
from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView

class MyView(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = 'pages/wizard_steps.html'
    template_name_done = 'pages/wizard_done.html'

    form_list = (
        ('upload', UploadSampleSheetForm),
        ('confirm', NewOrderForm)
    )

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        # you can get all forms data here and process it as you want
        return render(self.request, self.template_name_done, {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],  
        })

    def process_step(self, form):
        if isinstance(form, UploadSampleSheetForm):
            # Example. You can put here some additional manipulations
            pass
        return super().process_step(form)
```

And template

```
<!-- wizard_done.html -->
{% if wizard.steps.current == 'upload' %}
    {% include 'pages/wizard_upload.html' %}
{% elif wizard.steps.current == 'complete' %}
    {% include 'pages/wizard_complete.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for [Django Session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/). This is an extensive document if you want to dive deep.

It includes the examples that you are looking for as well.